# How to download website files from a server

Tags: windows, ftp, cmd

I have a website hosted on a server `***.***.**.**`

I would like to download a folder, `public_html` which contains my website files.

How can I download the folder with all it's subdirectories intact and in order?

I'm using:

```
binary
cd public_html
lcd D:\websiteFiles
mget */*
```

but, the problem is that this dumps all the contents of `public_html` and its sub-folders into `websiteFiles` without the sub-folders.

how can I maintain the structure of `public_html` and all its sub-folders on download?

I want to do this in windows 7 cmd without assistance from ftp tools like fireftp, filzilla....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative would be to use `wget` to do this. The following command should work as long as you have `wget` installed on your system:

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P . http://example.com/public_html
```

You might have to add a `Referer` header to your request:

```
--header "Referer: exampe.com"
```

Another way would be to use `rsync`:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh <username>@<server>:/public_html/ /www/
```

You can download `wget` here https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

The `scp` command can also be used to achieve this:

```
scp -r <username>@<server>:/public_html /www/
```

You could install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) in order to use `rsync` or `scp`

Comment: Thanks for the response, Cyclone. I had tried wget, even that approach: `wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P . http://example.com/public_html` before. The problem is that I only get access to the 404.html file and the cgi-sys folder. There are a number of folders in the root of the site. I get nothing from public_html.

Comment: @user3663765 - Seems very strange. Can you try to add a `Referer` header like: `wget --header "Referer: example.com" --mirror -p --convert-links -P . http://example.com/public_html`. Can you give me a link to the page so I can try for myself?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
wget -m ftp://username:password@ip.of.old.host
```

...